# A very simple percentage question or is it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

If $z\% \text{ of }x = y, \text{ given } x,y$ are natural numbers and $50.5\le z \lt 51.5$, then what is the smallest possible value of $x$?

Answer (score 2):

We're looking for a fraction that is just a bit more than 1/2, and must exceed it by less than 0.015 = 3/200.

If the denominator is even, say $2n$, the first fraction bigger than 1/2 is $\frac{n + 1}{2n}$, which exceeds 1/2 by $1/2n$, so $1/2n <  3/200$, hence $2n > 200/3$. So the denominator $2n$ is at least 68.

If the denominator is odd, say $2n + 1$, the first fraction bigger than 1/2 is $\frac{n + 1}{2n + 1}$, which exceeds 1/2 by $1/2(2n + 1)$, so $1/2(2n + 1) <  3/200$, hence $2n + 1 > 100/3$. So the denominator $2n + 1$ is at least 35.

In all cases then, the denominator must be at least 35. Since 18/35 is in the right interval, it is the best possible answer.

Answer (score 1):

That $y$ is $z\%$ of $x$ means

$$\frac{y}{x} = \frac{z}{100}.$$

So you are looking for the smallest positive integer $x$ such that there is a positive integer $y$ with

$$\frac{101}{200} \leqslant \frac{y}{x} < \frac{103}{200}.$$

That is equivalent to

$$\frac{101x}{200} < \left\lfloor \frac{103x}{200}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{101x}{200} + \frac{2x}{200}\right\rfloor.$$

If $x = 2k$, we have $\frac{101x}{200} = k + \frac{k}{100}$, and $\frac{103x}{200} = k + \frac{3k}{100}$, so we need $3k > 100$, which leads to $k = 34$ and $x = 68$. If $x = 2k+1$, then

$$\frac{101x}{200} = k + \frac12 + \frac{2k+1}{200}$$

and

$$\frac{103x}{200} = k + \frac12 + \frac{6k+3}{200},$$

so we need $2k+1 < 100 < 6k+3$, and one sees that $k = 17$ is the smallest possibility. Hence $x = 2\cdot 17 + 1 = 35$.

Comment: why 3K > 100? And why did you use the floor function?

Comment: It must be at least $k+1$ to have an integer between the two fractions, and using the floor function gives that integer that must lie between the two.